# строки вывода toString() не отображаются корректно

Tags: java

Всем привет. Пытаюсь пройтись по коллекции строковых массивов и вывести на экран содержимое. Специально переписал метод toString(), но почему-то данные все равно не отображаются как надо. Скорее всего я не совсем понимаю, как работать с конструкцией for(List<*String[]*> str : list). Помогите разобарться.

```
public class CSVReader {

    private static List<String[]> data = new LinkedList<String[]>();
    private static String[] dataRecords;

    // This function read data  from CSV file and return as a list
    public static List<String[]> read(String file){
        String dataRow;;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while((dataRow = br.readLine()) != null) {
                dataRecords = dataRow.split(",");
                data.add(dataRecords);
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String name = dataRecords[0];
        String sSN = dataRecords[1];
        String accountType = dataRecords[2];
        double initDeposit = Double.parseDouble(dataRecords[3]);
        return "Name: " + name + 
               " SSN: " + sSN + 
               " Account type: " + accountType + 
               " $" + initDeposit;
        }
}


public class BankAccountApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file = "C:\\JavaProjects\\BankAccount\\NewBankAccounts.csv";

        List<String[]> newAccounts = utils.CSVReader.read(file);
        for(String[] str : newAccounts) {
           System.out.println(str.toString()); // выведет class@hashcode
           System.out.println(str[0]);         // выводит данные корректно
           System.out.println(str[1]);
           System.out.println(str[2]);
           System.out.println(str[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы не тот `toString` переопределяете

Comment: и зачем вам два static поля `private static List<String[]> data` достаточно использовать локальные переменные в методе `read`

Comment: и как он у вас вообще работает, если `utils` у вас вообще не объявлен?

Comment: @Farkhod Daniyarov utils - это название пакета

Comment: тогда, когда добавляете код, нужно добавлять его полностью, в месте и блоком `package` и блоки `importa` иначе такой код, не возможно запустить.

Comment: еще момент, вы не закрываете открытый файл `br`, это тоже не есть хорошо.

Comment: @Farkhod Daniyarov спасибо за советы, исправлюсь)

Comment: без проблем, рад помочь :)

Comment: @Farkhod Daniyarov Я привел код внизу, реализациякоторого удовлетворяет моим изначальным требованиям. Но теперь у меня еще 1 вопрос: возможно ли получить такой же вывод, переписав метод toString()?

Comment: смотрите, у вас `newAccounts` он из массивов `String[]`, объект `String` в Java вроде как финальный, вы не сможете переопределить его метод `toString()`, у вас в `arr` массив, обращайтесь к нему по индексу и сделайте нужный вывод. Если не справитесь, отпишитесь, обновлю свой ответ.

Comment: @Farkhod Daniyarov Я, вроде бы, так и сделал

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

...

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

По идее, ваш код мог бы выглядит вот так

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

class CSVReader {
    static List<String[]> read(String file){
        List<String[]> result = new LinkedList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String dataRow;
            while((dataRow = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] dataRecords = dataRow.split(",");
                result.add(dataRecords);
            }

        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file = "C:\\JavaProjects\\BankAccount\\NewBankAccounts.csv";
        List<String[]> newAccounts = CSVReader.read(file);
        for(String[] obj : newAccounts) {
            // Тут можно производить вывод
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Привожу пример кода, который я хотел

```
package utils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class CSVReader {

    // This function read data  from CSV file and return as a list
    public static List<String[]> read(String file){
        List<String[]> data = new LinkedList<String[]>();
        String[] dataRecords;
        String dataRow;;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while((dataRow = br.readLine()) != null) {
                dataRecords = dataRow.split(",");
                data.add(dataRecords);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static String toString(String[] arr) {
        String name = arr[0];
        String sSN = arr[1];
        String accountType = arr[2];
        double initDeposit = Double.parseDouble(arr[3]);
        return "Name: " + name + "; " +
               "SSN: " + sSN + "; " +
               "Account type: " + accountType + "; " +
               "Deposit $" + initDeposit;
    }
}



import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class BankAccountApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file = "C:\\JavaProjects\\BankAccount\\NewBankAccounts.csv";

        List<String[]> newAccounts = utils.CSVReader.read(file);

        // Как предложили вы
        for(String[] strAccount : newAccounts) {
            String str = Arrays.toString(strAccount);
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        System.out.println("********************************************************");
        // Как хотел я
        for(int i = 0; i < newAccounts.size(); i ++) {
            String[] arr = newAccounts.get(i);
            String arrr = utils.CSVReader.toString(arr);
            System.out.println(arrr);
        }
    }
}
```

Ниже приведена часть вывода. Второй вариант - то, чего я пытался достичь.

```
OUTPUT:
[Arielle Duncan, 444102638, Savings, 1000]
[Marybeth Sanders, 431551383, Checking, 2500]
[Hattie Storey, 476687875, Checking, 3500]
*****************************************************************************
Name: Arielle Duncan; SSN: 444102638; Account type: Savings; Deposit $1000.0
Name: Marybeth Sanders; SSN: 431551383; Account type: Checking; Deposit $2500.0
Name: Hattie Storey; SSN: 476687875; Account type: Checking; Deposit $3500.0
```